# Excel VBA script looping not working fine

Tags: excel, vba

When B21 is blank and I click on D21 cell, I get shown error 2 and error 1(this is not expected as I am expecting only error 1). But when I click on E21 cell I get shown only Error 2 which is expected.

I am not sure where am I going wrong ?

My code is below:

```
If [B21] = "" Then
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
         If Target.Row = 21 Then
            Beep
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
            MsgBox "1.Error"
         End If
    ElseIf Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Row = 21 Then
            Beep
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
            MsgBox "2.Error"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

When your code selects a cell, that also triggers the event handler. Typically you would prevent that by setting `Application.EnableEvents = False` (don't forget to set it back to `True` later...) –

Comment: still don't understand why would that show error twice in once case and just once in the other case?

Comment: when you click on D your code then selects E which triggers the code again, and finally F gets selected.  When you click on E there's only one move.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to Tim Williams's solution is a worksheet scoped variable to keep track of when E21 cell is being selected by your code itself

so your worksheet code would be:

```
    Dim dontBeep As Boolean

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If [B21] = "" Then
        If Target.Column = 4 Then
             If Target.Row = 21 Then
                Beep
                dontBeep = True ' make sure subsequent E21 cell selection would not trigger any beep and action
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
                MsgBox "1.Error"
             End If
        ElseIf Target.Column = 5 Then
            If Target.Row = 21 Then
                If dontBeep Then
                    dontBeep = False ' restore default triggering conditions
                Else
                    Beep
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
                    MsgBox "2.Error"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

you could also take row index check at the beginning, since it's the same for both relevant columns:

```
Dim dontBeep As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If [B21] = "" Then
        If Target.Row = 21 Then
            If Target.Column = 4 Then
               Beep
               dontBeep = True ' make sure subsequent E21 cell selection would not trigger any beep and action

               Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
               MsgBox "1.Error"
            ElseIf Target.Column = 5 Then
                If dontBeep Then
                    dontBeep = False
                Else
                    Beep' restore default triggering conditions
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
                    MsgBox "2.Error"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```